# Attaching event handlers in Visual Basic .NET

Tags: vb.net, events

What’s the equivalent of the C# `+=` operator when used to add event handlers in VB.NET?

```cs
TreeView1.TreeNodeDataBound += new TreeNodeEventHandler(TreeView1_TreeNodeDataBound);
```

Comment: You'd normally use the Handles keyword in VB.NET, that's what the designer uses.  But AddHandler is fine too.

Answer (score 4):

Something like:

```
AddHandler TreeView1.TreeNodeDataBound, AddressOf TreeView1_TreeNodeDataBound
```

Answer (score 1):

First define a method with the same signature as the event and use the [AddHandler Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7taxzxka%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to tie the event with the method.